# get value from database table where id = ? java

Tags: java, sql, jsp, derby

I have one table 
[Table name is PARKTABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsgre.jpg)

Now I want to get these values in jsp 
my code is here

```
 <jsp:useBean id="loginBean" scope="session" class="vustudent.Login" />
        <input type="text" name="takei" value='<jsp:getProperty name="loginBean" property="loginid" />' />
        <%
            String dbId = request.getParameter("takei");
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            String url= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true; user=app; password=app";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
            Statement st= con.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM PARKTABLE WHERE ID =\'"+ dbId + "\' ";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            // iterate through the java resultset
      if (rs.next())
      {
        String placeOne = rs.getString("Place1");
        String placeTwo = rs.getString("Place2"); 
        System.out.println("place1" +placeOne);
        System.out.println("place1" +placeTwo);
      }
        %>
        </br>
        <input type="text" name="pl1value" value='placeOne' />
```

it prints placeOne in input text field istead of its value. 
I want to print placeOne value red or green from database. 
where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your input text as below:

```
<input type="text" name="pl1value" value='<%=placeOne%>' />
```

And then, change your `Java` code as below:

```
String placeOne = "";
String placeTwo = "";

 if (rs.next())
      {
        placeOne = rs.getString("Place1");
        placeTwo = rs.getString("Place2"); 
        System.out.println("place1" +placeOne);
        System.out.println("place1" +placeTwo);
      }
```

So your input type can print default value even your query return no data.

Comment: i think it should be work. but I didn't declare id = primary key yet. May be due to this issue. it could be the reason or not?

Comment: get your String query value and run in database and then let me know query is ok or not. But it's not related with primary key. It's optional but good to have one pk in one table

Comment: when I wrote
String query = "SELECT * FROM PARKTABLE WHERE ID = '126678' ";
its works fine and get red value in input field but 
when i wrote 
String query = "SELECT * FROM PARKTABLE WHERE ID = 'dbId' ";
it return empty input box.

Comment: and also \ is no need in your query, you can delete.

Comment: its printing null value. I don't know why? can you tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: its too long by 1047 characters allowed in comment box

Comment: so delete takei input text box value attribute and put 126678  manually and let me know it's ok or not.

Comment: yes it is ok but I don't want to dell it I want to take its value in dbId.

Comment: so just figure out how to get input text value from JSP scriptlet as to your case. but you know what the error is and answer is enough I guess.

Comment: In future, try to separate JSP code and Servlet code, try to use PreparedStatement instead of Statement.

Answer (score 2):

Three changes are necessary

```
  String placeOne = null; // declare here
  String placeTwo = null; 
  if (rs.next())
  {
    placeOne = rs.getString("Place1");  // set value here
    placeTwo = rs.getString("Place2"); 
    System.out.println("place1" +placeOne);
    System.out.println("place1" +placeTwo);
  }
    %>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="pl1value" value=''<%=placeOne%>' />  // print here
```

Comment: @FatimaEman , yes, it's work! But you need to understand your program logic and also you need to make sure your query is correct or not.

Comment: I didn't make id = primary key yet. this could be the reason??

Comment: no error just printing null value in input field box

Answer (score 0):

As Scary Wombat and Ye Win posts, they are logically correct. If I were you, I would actually use `PreparedStatement` rather than `Statement`. and I will use `while` statement rather than `if`. see my code below.

```
        String dbId = request.getParameter("takei");
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        String url= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true; user=app; password=app";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
        String query = "SELECT * FROM PARKTABLE WHERE ID = ?";
        PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(0,dbId);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

        String placeOne = null;
        String placeTwo = null;

        while (rs.next()) {
            String placeOne = rs.getString("Place1");
            String placeTwo = rs.getString("Place2"); 
            System.out.println("place1" +placeOne);
            System.out.println("place1" +placeTwo);
        }
```

I use PreparedStatement to prevent SQL Injection like you did on your Statement but it is more readable and clean when other programmer see it. I used while to retrieve all your results in your `ResultSet`.